# How to organize app structure with different types of user?

Tags: android, user-interface, user-experience

I have app with 2 different types of users. The first type is sellers and second -buyers. So the UI in the app depends who using this app, buyer or seller. So, how to organize the app structure? Because it is bad idea, to hide and show each item depend on the Role of user, is there are better way?

Comment: Make 2 apps if the UI is completely different. If not just check user type and have different activities I guess, so for sellers you have MainSeller and for user buyer you can have MainBuyer.. Don't know how your layout looks like but take a look at what fragments do, they might come in very handy..

Comment: Thanks, and what about android modules? Is it possible to change modules  depend on the user role? https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/create-project.html

Comment: you can have multiple modules added to your project of course

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flavors`concept. This may be helpful: [android flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)